# Can I use collection initializers with a NameValueCollection?

Tags: c#, collections

Is there a way to initialize a NVC using C# collection initializer syntax:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection() { ("a", "1"), ("b", "2") };
```

Thanks

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Yes; just uses braces instead of parentheses.

```
var nvc = new NameValueCollection { {"a", "1"}, {"b", "2"} };
```

You can call `Add` methods with arbitrary sets of parameters using the syntax.

Comment: The MSDN page on *Object and Collection Initialization* outlines exactly why `NameValueCollection` accepts this syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: @six: Actually, it doesn't even mention this syntax.

Comment: Good catch, it appears to be buried in the page for `Dictionary<K,V>` initialization, "or any collection whose Add method takes multiple parameters," http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx

Answer (score 8):

You can use collection initializers with everything that has `Add` method. Yeah, duck typing. If `Add` has more then 1 param put tuples in curly bracets:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection() { { "a", "1" }, { "b", "2" } };
```

Comment: Not quite; it must implement `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Implements `System.Collections.IEnumerable` AND has an `Add` method taking at least 1 argument.

Comment: @SLaks yes, i forgot about it. Btw it is rather strange requirement, because this construction doesn't use IEnumerable's methods.

Comment: Because the base class `NameObjectCollectionBase` that uses `IEnumerable`. It is a lesson for me before if you want to check what was the implementation used make sure you check all the base type up to `System.Object`.